# "Using Verb Tenses in Sequence"

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

http://www.arts.uottawa.ca/writcent/hypergrammar/vbseq.html

Here, what does 'sequence' mean? Does it mean 'multiple sentences'? Or it means 'a paragraph'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sympathise with anyone having to learn English as a second language, I really do. That explanation even confused me, a native speaker! What I think they mean by verb sequence is the order in which verbs appear in a sentence containing two clauses.

Try this site for more info:

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sequence.htm

Comment: That website makes very little sense. What can "... whose cradle tongue does not uses a similar tense system ..." mean! +1 for the link.

Comment: @Tragicomic, yes, is 'cradle tongue' something specific to Canada, or just PC for mother tongue?